# Captcha doesn't work correctly in Railo using CFIMAGE

Tags: fonts, captcha, railo, cfimage

I was playing around with CAPTCHA in Railo using CFIMAGE recently and for some reason I 
couldn't make it work correctly. It generates the image and it 
shows up in the browser, but the font looks strange and the letters 
are placed all over, usually one half on top and the other on the 
bottom of the image.

Here's my code:

> <cfimage action="captcha" width="250" height="80" text="RAILO" 
>   fonts="arial,verdana,times new roman, courier" fontsize="20" 
>   difficulty="low" />

And this is what it generates:
http://lecws.com/captcha.cfm

Is there anything I'm missing? Do I have to install fonts on the 
server? I'm running Railo 3.1.2.001 final on CentOS 5.3 64bit. 
Any help is appreciated.

George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution in case someone else runs into this issue.

I had to install fonts on my server. I did so using the accepted solution on this page:
www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Linux/Administration/Q_23644439.html

Then I had to restart Railo so that it read the new fonts and the problem was fixed.

Big thanks to the [Railo Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/railo) for helping me with this.